# Could not find method compileSdk() for arguments [33] on object of type com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension

Tags: flutter

I am Getting this error

What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':cloud_firestore'.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Program Files\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 468
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':cloud_firestore'.

> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> Cannot invoke method substring() on null object
> compileSdkVersion is not specified.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  ==============================================================================
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

build.gradle file

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 26

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
}

lintOptions {
    disable 'InvalidPackage'
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.devloper.studio"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
        // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
}
```

}